# Why can't collections and comparators be passed at once in constructor?

Tags: java, api, sorting, collections

I have observed this in a couple of java API's that eg: TreeSet, PriorityQueue etc that there is no constructor that takes both `Collection` and `Comparator`. Instead we have to pick one of the constructor that takes `Comparator` and use addAll to pass in the `Collection`

Eg:

```
TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c)
Constructs a new tree set containing the elements in the specified collection, sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements.
TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the specified comparator.
```

Is this just an insufficient/inflexible API? Or it is a genuine reason to split them out  that I am not aware of? 
In other words, I am trying to ask why dont we have a constructor like `TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c, Comparator<? super E> comparator)`?

Comment: The third option is `TreeSet(SortedSet<E>)`, which uses the same sort ordering as the source set.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking. Do you want a constructor like TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c, Comparator<? super E> comparator) ??

Comment: Can you clarify why you want such a constructor? While there's no arguing that it would be convenient to have one, if you could give us a more accurate description of your specific situation, perhaps we can suggest ways to keep your code clear and clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that a `TreeSet(Collection)` constructor exists at all is an additional convenience to begin with. Internally, [the implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/TreeSet.java?av=f) simply calls the `Comparator` constructor then `addAll()`.

I'd imagine they simply did not include further conveniences. There is no particular reason why such a constructor *couldn't* exist.

However, conceptually, it is a little odd to specify both a source collection and an initial comparator, since constructing a `TreeSet` by specifying a collection to the constructor, to me at least, indicates that the resulting `TreeSet` will be a copy of the input set (in that it contains the same elements) - simply by convention.

Being able to supply a `Comparator` in addition to a `Collection` allows for the possibility that the new `TreeSet` does *not* end up containing the same elements if, e.g., the input was another `TreeSet` but the new `Comparator` makes some elements identical. To that end, forcing you to call `addAll()` in such a case also forces you to use code that clearly indicates your intentions.

<strike>That said, if the natural ordering of the items in the source collection conflict with any comparator that a source set may have used, it still presents the same possibility when `TreeSet(Collection)` is used.</strike>

Edit:

The previous statement isn't quite true. If the source set is the type of set that uses a custom comparator, then it is actually a `SortedSet`, and the [`TreeSet(SortedSet)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.SortedSet%29) constructor is used instead, which takes on the same comparator as the source set. So unless you go out of your way to construct a non-`SortedSet` middle-man, the current collection of `TreeSet` constructors will not let you create a `TreeSet` that leads to a different set of elements than the source had. In other words: By not providing the `Collection`+`Comparator` constructor you are asking about, the designers have also eliminated the possibility of changing the comparator via constructor; thus a newly constructed `TreeSet` will *always* have the same elements in it as the source collection, in all cases. This is a compelling reason to not provide that constructor (and also suggests the reason for a separate `SortedSet` constructor to exist at all).

Additionally, perhaps the designers simply chose to draw the convenience line at the constructors they provided.

---

As an aside: The bonus effect of the `SortedSet` constructor is that it eliminates the possibility of a mistake like this:

```
void doWork (Set<E> items) {
    TreeSet<E> workingSet = new TreeSet<E>(items);
    ...
}
```

And having `workingSet` inadvertently end up containing a subset of `items` (e.g. if `items` was a `HashSet` then `workingSet` uses natural ordering and it's fine, but if `items` was a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator, and `workingSet` used the natural ordering that happened to conflict with the comparator, then there would be a problem). The current set of constructors forces you to clearly display intent and explicitly take any actions that may change the comparator.