# how to use both Comparator and Arrays.asList in TreeSet

Tags: java, collections

Friends, I am facing a problem in `TreeSet` Collection. The problem is that I want to use both `Comparator` and `Arrays.asList()` method in `TreeSet`'s constructor.

```
void addDataFromArrays(){
    Toy t1=new Toy();
    t1.setId(123);
    t1.setName("cubes");

    Toy t2=new Toy();
    t2.setId(321);
    t2.setName("balls");

    Toy t3=new Toy();
    t3.setId(124);
    t3.setName("teddys");

    Toy arr[]={t1,t2,t3};

Set<Toy> set=new TreeSet<Toy>(new ToyComp(),Arrays.asList(sa));  // error in this line
}
```

the error goes away if I use `Comparable` in `Toy` class, thus eliminating one of the parameter from `TreeSet` constructor. But, still I want to use `Comparator`.

Comment: `Set<Toy> set=new TreeSet<Toy>(new ToyComp()); set.addAll(Arrays.asList(sa));`

Comment: If you look at the [online API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), you'll see that `TreeSet` doesn't have a constructor that takes multiple arguments. You'll have to add the array in a separate line, as ZouZou showed

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597067/why-cant-collections-and-comparators-be-passed-at-once-in-constructor

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't. But you can do:

```
Set<Toy> set=new TreeSet<Toy>(new ToyComp());
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(sa));
```